# Image not loading through firebase Storage flutter

Tags: flutter

Image network request

```
Image.network(
                  FirebaseStorage.instance
                      .ref()
                      .child(blog.data["picture1"])
                      .getDownloadURL()
                      .toString(),
                ),
```

picture1 is a string in a format - "blogPic/${email}/${number}_a".
This string points to the firestorage location.

Error

```
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: Image(image: NetworkImage("Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'", scale: 1.0), frameBuilder: null, loadingBuilder: null, alignment: center, this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:664:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:648:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:13)
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "Image(image: NetworkImage("Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'", scale: 1.0), frameBuilder: null, loadingBuilder: null, alignment: center, this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#33ea4(), name: "Image(image: NetworkImage("Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'", scale: 1.0), frameBuilder: null, loadingBuilder: null, alignment: center, this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)", scale: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

using FutureBuilder Widget

```
                                FutureBuilder(builder: (context , snapshot){
                                    switch(snapshot.connectionState){
                                      case ConnectionState.none:
                                        return Text('No Data');
                                        break;
                                      case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                        return Container(
                                          width: 200,
                                          height: 200,
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                        );
                                        break;
                                      case ConnectionState.active:
                                        return Container(
                                          width: 200,
                                          height: 200,
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                        );
                                        break;
                                      case ConnectionState.done:
                                        return Container(
                                          width: 200,
                                          height: 200,
                                          child: Image.network(snapshot.data.toString() , fit: BoxFit.contain,),
                                        );
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    return Container(
                                      width: 200,
                                      height: 200,
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                    );
                                  }, future: _getImage(document['filePath']),)

  Future<String> _getImage(filePath) async{
    String url = await storage.ref().child('launch').child('$filePath.jpg').getDownloadURL().whenComplete((){
    }).catchError((error){
      return null;
    });
    return url;
  }
```